# JQuery $post()-Method seems like doing nothing

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a html/javascript frontend and a php backend and wanted to transmit a json-stringarray from my frontend to backend with ajax. Unfortunately it doesn't work and i dont know why. The following code doesn't work for me:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function sendData(){
            $.post("test.php", {}, function(data){
                $("#output").val(data);
            });
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="button" value="send" onclick="sendData()">
    <p id="output"></p>

</body>
```

The test.php file looks like:

```
<?php
     echo "this text has been send back";
?>
```

If i am correct, by clicking the button, there should be displayed response from the ajax-query but nothing happens. I guess something is wrong but i can't see where the problem is.

Best regards

Comment: you dont need {} if you arent sending any data. and the .html(data) answers are why you arent seeing the response. .val() is for input types

Answer (score 1):

chenge below code . use  [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) not [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
$("#output").html(data);
```

change function to below . don't need to use {}

```
 function sendData(){
        $.post("test.php",function(data){
            $("#output").html(data);
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's your jQuery thats wrong. the p tag doesnt use $.val(); it uses $.html().